# [Rails]has_many - No such column user.event_id...

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I've got a problem with 2 of my models. Here it is :

My User class can have many events

```
  has_many :events
```

My Event can have many Users but belongs to one (the administrator)

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :album
  has_many :guests, :class_name => User
```

Now, when I'm trying to acces the guests of an event which an user created

```
event.guests.count #Like that
```

Rails returns me a SQL error

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.event_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."event_id" = ?

This is pretty strange for me because a user can have several events so a event_id column is not necessary there (my point of view). I guess I'm wrong because if I wasn't, I wouldn't get this error.
Is there any "conflict" between belongs_to and has_many ?

Could someone explain to me why I'm getting this and how to resolve it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone explain to me why I'm getting this...

The first part of the method call is `event.guests`

You have a `has_many` association set up in your `Event` model with `has_many :guests, :class_name => User`

So active record is going to look in your `users` table for a column called `event_id` (which doesn't exist) hence the error.

> ...and how to resolve it ?

Add an `event_id` column to your users table along with `belongs_to :event` in your `User` model is one option, but you'd better off using a `has_many :through` approach as you've just discovered.

Answer (score 0):

I finally, created another model and used the has_many :through method. Is it really needed ? Because create a table for relations only seems to be pretty heavy.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to create a bridge table any time you need to represent a many-to-many relationship in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`

`has_many` is a one-to-many relationship. It doesn't care what `User`'s associations are. It's just trying to do a lookup for all users with that event's ID in the event_id column, hence your error.

But you're dealing with many-to-many.

[Full Explanation on has_and_belongs_to_many here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

[Also read how to pick between has_and_belongs_to vs has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)
Basically, use has_and_belongs_to_many if you wont need to use the join model as an independent entity. Both require a join table to be created however.

Answer (score 0):

think it this way:

1) user has_many events and event belongs_to user. hence events table should have a field user_id. This specifies that @user.events will fetch all the events for the user and @event.user will fetch the user to whom the event belongs.

2) event has_many guests, class_name: 'User'. Here, @events.guests will fetch all the users(because you have specified a different class name. if you haven't had specified so, it would have looked for a model called Guest and a corresponding table named 'guests' in database). Since, guest(ie user) is a child model of event, it need to store the 'event_id' for reference.

ie. a child model object should always have a reference of parent object (ie parent_id).